# Encoding/Escaping Spaces for URL GET Request JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get, request

I'm currently trying to handle a bug in my system where my GET requests to query my database cannot handle spaces. My GET request in JavaScript looks like so and I am 100% sure works for cases without spaces :

```
let values = JSON.parse(ajax().sync().get(url));
```

For an example of the bug, take the following URL:

```
localhost:8000/database/data?id_one=one&id_two=one hundred
```

Obviously, passing that in returns nothing because I'm not accounting for the space. So I then try to escape the space with '%20' like so:

```
localhost:8000/database/data?id_one=one&id_two=one%20hundred
```

However, this is still returning nothing, as I can see on the server-side that it is passing in the URL with '%20' as a literal into the query; it's querying the database for  'one%20hundred' and not 'one hundred'. I can tell becasue the 'GET' on the server side looks like this:

```
GET localhost:8000/database/data?id_one=one&id_two=one%20hundred 304 1.877 ms
```

How do I escape a space like this to query the database properly? I've tried using '+' in place of '%20' but that's not solving it either unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered deconstructing the request server side? I assume you're using Node.JS with Express. If this is the case try to remove the special characters (+ and %20) in the `req.param.id_two`.

Comment: Perfect answer, I was trying to handle it client-side over server before just like you said.
I handled it like so for anyone else who might stumble along the same issue:
`req.param.id_two = req.param.id_two.replace(/%20/g,' ') ` (I use a regex in .replace() to replace all instances of '%20' with spaces)
Thank you so much!